# Efficiently get the number of distinct dates in a list of np.datetime64 elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.00001*np.pi)
base = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
arr = np.array([base + timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(len(x))])
y = np.sin(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': [np.datetime64(x) for x in arr], 'vals': y})
```

which creates the following dataframe with 1-minute data:

```
                dates      vals
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00  0.000000
1 2000-01-01 00:01:00  0.000031
2 2000-01-01 00:02:00  0.000063
3 2000-01-01 00:03:00  0.000094
4 2000-01-01 00:04:00  0.000126
```

I want to retrieve the number of distinct dates in a `yyyy-mm-dd` format efficiently.

My current solution is the following, but seems to be quite slow:

```
distinct_days = set([str(i.date()) for i in pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])])

{'2000-03-29', '2000-02-14', '2000-01-30', '2000-03-04',...
```

and then I just do `len(distinct_days)` to get the desired result (i.e. `139`).

Is there a way to do this faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something simpler using pandas itself:

```
>>> df["only_date"] = df["date"].dt.date
>>> df["only_date"].nunique()
# 139
```

Comment: Amazing thanks! May I also ask you how to apply it on a DatetimeIndex? Say "date" is now the index of my dataframe, then do I have to do `df.reset_index()["date"].dt.date.nunique() ` (as this makes it slow again)?

Comment: No, if the datetime values are your index, you can just used `df["only_date"] = df.index.date`

Comment: And then apply `set` instead of `nunique` I guess ?

Comment: Just replace the first line of code with that. That's all

Comment: Ok, provided that you assign a new column "only_date" to your initial dataframe, otherwise it will not work on the fly. Thanks, will mark the question as solved ;)